# Confused about using UNION or JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, join, union

I have three MySQL tables: 'people', 'people2id', 'places'. The first one stores information about people, where the 'places' table stores information about their addresses. The middle one, 'people2id', interconnects this two tables (could be that one person has two or more addresses).

Now I want to go to some person's profile and see his profile, but also his associated addresses. I created this query for that:

```
 SELECT * FROM people p
 JOIN people2id e ON p.peopleId = e.peopleId
 JOIN places a ON a.peopleId = e.peopleId
 WHERE p.peopleId = number
```

This works when the person has associated address(es), otherwise, it will fail. I do not understand if I should use any kind of JOIN or use UNION for this matter.

Comment: Is there any specific reason to create extra table `people2id` just to relate you can directly relate peoples with places each place should have people_id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the `JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`, i.e.

```
 SELECT * FROM people p
 LEFT JOIN people2id e ON p.peopleId = e.peopleId
 LEFT JOIN places a ON a.peopleId = e.peopleId
 WHERE p.peopleId = number
```

Using `LEFT JOIN` will include all the records from `people`, whether they contain associated records or not.

Comment: Thank you, I understand LEFT JOIN now.

Answer (score 2):

**UNION** is used for get same kind of informations from two different queries and return them as a single result set

**JOIN** is used for *add columns and data to rows* (not as simple but you can see it like this)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT * FROM people p
JOIN people2id e ON p.peopleId = e.peopleId
LEFT JOIN places a ON a.peopleId = e.peopleId
WHERE p.peopleId = number
```

Comment: Will you please remove the w3schools link?